# URL-ROUTING for Asp.Net MVC Action parameter binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, parameter-passing, controller-action

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 for the first time. I want to call a controller action with a single parameter. this parameter is an object, not a simple type. Let's say:
Controller = "Person", 
Action="Add", 
The single argument of this action is an object: "Person" = {Name: "aaa", Age: 24}

I implement the ModelBinder neaded for such a parameter (Person). I am calling this action from the client with the following instruction:

```
var person= {}; 
person.Name = "aaa"; person.Age = 24;
var **url = '/Person/Add/' + $.param(person)**;
**window.location = url;**
```

This is my first program in Asp.NET MVC. I thing this is the right way to write the 'url'.
Could you please help me to **create the variable 'url'** (needed to call the server action) **in the right format** ?

Thinks

Comment: You mentioned ModelBinder in your question... Do you wish to add the Person Model, based on user input? Or am I'm not reading this correctly?\

Comment: Actually I added this code in the server part. But I am using in the client part an URL which is badly interpreted by the server. It seems the way of writining the URL. If I have a complex JSON object with a vector, is there a way to transform it to an URL that suits the Asp.NET MVC server router? THINKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass that in the querystring like this

```
var thatUrl = "/Person/Add?Name=aaa&age=24";
thatUrl=encodeURI(thatUrl);  //Let's encode :)
window.location.href=thatUrl;
```

Assumuing you have `HttpGET` Action method which is looks like either

```
public ActionResult Add(string Name,string Age)
{
  //you will have the values in the argumens. Do something now
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult Add(Person model)
{
  //you will have the values in the object
  //check for model.Name & model.Age
}
```

assuming Name and Age are 2 properties of `Person` class

Comment: Is there a simple way to send a more complex object from the client objet to the server (more complex than the object **Person = {Name: "aaa", Age: "24"}**. Should I implement a javascript function to transform this object to the URL, or a function exsists yet to do this transformation ? 
Thinks

Comment: If you are making a jQuery ajax call, you can send the data as JSON

Comment: I would like to have a new URL adresse. So I would like to use some thing like window.location, not an ajax call. Thinks

Comment: I would like to have a new URL adresse. So I would like to use some thing like window.location, not an ajax call. In this case do you know please how to get a URL from a complex JSON object to use it with a window.location instruction? Or do you know how to do it in another way? I would like to move to a new URL (to be RESTfull). I don't think that using ajax will help me for that. Thinks

Comment: If it is rest, you can pass the items in your Content body ,If it is POST and pass it in parameters if it is GET. I think this one of yours is POST. so you can pass it in content body.